# Can't enable "Make discoverable PulseAudio network sound devices available locally" on PulseAudio Preferences

Tags: pulseaudio

I want to check "Make discoverable PulseAudio network sound devices available locally" on this:

[PulseAudio window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inawv.png)

If I click on "Install" the window just closes and nothing happens. I did try running it as sudo but the same thing happens. Isn't there a way to do this via terminal?

Answer (score 2):

This thread helped:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/paprefs/+bug/829051/comments/56

Just do the following:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1 /usr/lib/pulse-13.99
```

And then make sure that `pulse-13.99` exists:

```
ls -1 /usr/lib | grep pulse
```

Comment: thanks, really sad that bug has existed since 2011

Answer (score 0):

And the bug is still around in 22.04 :-)

Except now you have to symlink `pulse-15.99.1+dfsg1` to `pulse-15.99`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-15.99.1+dfsg1 /usr/lib/pulse-15.99
```